# Invalid Selector exception in Edge browser while same element can be found without any exception in chrome browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to click on a element. When i run the test script on chrome browser the element gets clicked where as the same test script when i run on edge browser gives exception "InvalidSelectorException"

Image of element as found in chrome-[https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/20/83d0add716dce6bdb5d8b1c6bac09544-full.png]

Image of element as found in edge - [https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/20/6333dff18caf14f7440955587ee98228-full.png]

Xpath used in code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Dashboard')]"))
```

We can see that there is no Quotes in the "dashboard" element text in edge browser where as there are quotes in the element text in chrome.

Is this the reason for being an invalid selector in edge?

```
Dashboard.java:173  - Exception occured : 
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The specified selector is 
invalid.
For documentation on this error, please visit: 
https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 
14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'IND-L-SRAWAT', ip: '164.99.196.169', os.name: 
'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: 
'1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, 
browserVersion: 44.17763.1.0, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: 
normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), s 
etWindowRect: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 
30000}}
Session ID: 4BC8634F-5CCA-4747-BE2F-B7E4A0D59872
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[contains(text(),'Dashboard')]}
2019-08-19 17:02:44 INFO  SettingsUIOperationsTest.java:104  - Test Case 
Failed
```

Can anyone help me with some work around for it?

**** - EDIT ****

I got to know that

1. **.contains**(sometext)
2. **and** condition in Xpath
3. " **'** " Single quotes within double quotes

These all doesnt work with IE or Edge

I Tried same xpath with **Partial Link Text** and it worked .

Can anyone come up with explanations for it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `contains(text(),'Dashboard')` try to use either of the following solutions:

- Using `text()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Dashboard']"))
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Dashboard')]"))
  ```

Comment: Tried both still getting -> The specified selector is invalid. *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[text()='Dashboard'])]}*** same with the other xpath you suggested

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a test with your sample code in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 and Chrome. I find that your code is working fine without any error in both browser. I know that you are using JAVA code to make a test, here I use C# for this test with similar line of code.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#">Dashboard</a>

</body>
</html>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
            //IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"C:\Users\panchals\Desktop\tests\215.html");
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title.ToString());

            object element=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Dashboard')]"));
            Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output from both browser:

[image]

I suggest you to try to install the latest updates for your Windows OS to update the Edge browser and again try to make a test using my sample code to check whether resolves the issue or not.

If issue persist than try to provide your detailed code to produce the issue. We will again try to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I've only started working with Selenium Web Driver in the last few days but have found that the By.XPath method has some really weird behavior going on with it.

This was the XPath I was using (and it failed to find the element... though it 100% exists).

```
//a[contains(@href, '/Web/Login')])[2]
```

After trying a heap of different syntax to load via XPath (and failing), I decided to go back to Selenium IDE and export the task as Java (I'm C#) to see what was going on.

As it turns out, the exported Java Tests escape the single quotes in XPath... to something like this.

```
//a[contains(@href, \'/Web/Login\')])[2]
```

Hence, as soon as I modified my selector to escape the single quote, it worked fine.

Let me know if it works.

- Selenium Generated Test
  [image]

Comment: The execption still exists : **The specified selector is invalid.**
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[contains(text(),'Dashboard')]}***

Comment: Have you tried escaping the single quotes as I posted?

Comment: Yes i did try that . Anyways the issue is resolved. Edge does not support .contains(sometext) as xpath . I tried using CSS properties of element then it worked. Thank you anyway